# Is a voxel engine appropriate for a Minecraft-like game?

Tags: voxels, minecraft-modding

Why does Minecraft use polygons to draw the world terrain instead of voxels?  Would a voxel based rendering engine be appropriate for a fully destructible game world built out of cubes like Minecraft?  Would it be more efficient than using polygons?

Comment: What makes you think Minecraft doesn't use what is essentially a voxel representation of its world? I mean, what is your source for that statement? I always assumed it did.

Comment: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Map - Specifically: "Minecraft uses a voxel system which is an incremental 3D grid in which each grid point holds data for a single block."

Comment: While Minecraft does use a voxel representation of the world, it is rendered using polygons.  My question was why he didn't write a voxel renderer.

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood

Comment: voxel rendering using ray casting on the gpu is totally possible with today (or yesterday) gpus. With clever acc structs (which are simple for voxels) and clever memory usage you should be able to render incredible huge scene in realtime.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you think there's any chance notch'll change the rendering technique to lower Minecraft's system requirements?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Why does Minecraft use polygons to
>   draw the world terrain instead of
>   voxels?

Graphics hardware works with and renders triangles, so you have to use triangles if you want hardware acceleration. Most voxel renderers employ something like [Marching Cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) to extract a polygonal mesh from a voxel representation and present that; direct volume rendering is typically computational expensive.

> Would a voxel based rendering engine
>   be appropriate for a fully
>   destructible game world built out of
>   cubes like Minecraft?

Yes.

> Would it be more efficient than using
>   polygons?

Probably, but not because voxels are faster or cheaper to render (in fact, they're more expensive to render since you must convert the data set). Voxel representation lends itself to *manipulation* easier than polygons -- so it's much easier to add and remove chunks, bits and pieces of the world represented by the data set.

Comment: 9 years later, this still stands.